# Let $(X, {\cal E}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $B,C \in {\cal E}$. Show $\mu_B + \mu_C \leq \mu$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, {\cal E}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $B,C \in {\cal E}$.  Define $\mu_B:{\cal E} \to [0,\infty]$ by $\mu_B (E) = \mu(E\cap B)$. (I have already proved that this does indeed define a new measure).

Find a necessary and sufficient condition on sets $B,C \in \mathcal{E}$ such that $\mu_B + \mu_C \leq \mu$.

Any ideas?

Comment: If $\mathrm{B}$ and $\mathrm{C}$ are _disjoint_ then $\mu_{\mathrm{B} \cup \mathrm{C}} = \mu_{\mathrm{B}} + \mu_{\mathrm{C}}.$ This is a _sufficient_ condition. Likely, it is also necessary but that needs more thought.

Comment: Thanks, I did find this condition but struggled to find a proof that shows it is necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim.** For $\mu_{\mathrm{B}} + \mu_{\mathrm{C}} \leq \mu$ it is a necessary and sufficient condition that $\mu(\mathrm{B} \cap \mathrm{C}) = 0.$

*Proof.* If $\mu(\mathrm{B} \cap \mathrm{C}) = 0$ then $\mu_{\mathrm{B}} = \mu_{\mathrm{B} \setminus \mathrm{C}},$ and similarly interchanging the rôles of $\mathrm{B}$ and $\mathrm{C}.$ Hence, $\mu_{\mathrm{B}} + \mu_{\mathrm{C}} = \mu_{(\mathrm{B} \setminus \mathrm{C}) \cup (\mathrm{C} \setminus \mathrm{B})} \leq \mu_{\mathrm{X}} = \mu;$ the condition is therefore sufficient. It is also necessary for we can evaluate the inequality $\mu_{\mathrm{B}} + \mu_{\mathrm{C}} \leq \mu$ in $\mathrm{B} \cap \mathrm{C}$ to reach $0 \leq 2 \mu(\mathrm{B} \cap \mathrm{C}) \leq \mu(\mathrm{B} \cap \mathrm{C}),$ hence $\mu(\mathrm{B} \cap \mathrm{C}) = 0.$ Q.E.D.

Comment: How did you show $\mu_B = \mu_{B\setminus C}$?

Comment: Because $\mu_\mathrm{B}(\mathrm{E}) = \mu(\mathrm{E} \cap (\mathrm{B} \setminus \mathrm{C})) + \mu(\mathrm{E} \cap \mathrm{B} \cap \mathrm{C}).$